# jQuery slider with setInterval not working correctly with fadeIn on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a very simple jQuery based slider with fadeIn on pageload. But i have problems with the cycling of the script after the first time.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
    function slideShow(isFirst) {
        if(isFirst) {
            $('#slider_img_1').delay(1500);
        }
        $('#slider_img_1').fadeIn(2000).delay(1000).fadeOut(2000); // 6500
        $('#slider_img_2').delay(5500).fadeIn(2000).delay(1000).fadeOut(2000); // 10500
        $('#slider_img_3').delay(9500).fadeIn(2000).delay(1000).fadeOut(2000); // 14500
    }

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        slideShow(true);
        setInterval("slideShow(false)",14500); 
    });
```

As you can see i simply add a delay to `img_1` for the first cycle. In the second cycle i loop through the slideshow again with the same duration as the total cycle should take.

But something goes wrong when the interval starts, first with a gap then very widespread delays.

Based on Arun's fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h2jwqhom/2/

Comment: Can you create a problem fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h2jwqhom/1/ ?

Comment: I have adde `position` to @ArunPJohny's example, which is exactly what i have done.

Comment: @JavaCake so what is the problem

Comment: The cycling between 3 back to 1 is not correct. I cant seem to figure out how i can fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to synchronize separate intervals, it's probably easier to work slide by slide. This can be accomplished by getting the next slide on each run:

```
var sliders = $('.slider_img') //obtain slide collection
   , cur = 0; //indexer for slides

function slideShow() {    
    var $slider = $(sliders[cur++]); //get slide to show
    if(cur>=sliders.length) cur=0; //check if next slide is within bounds
    $slider.fadeIn(2000).delay(1000).fadeOut(2000); //animate
    setTimeout(slideShow,3500); //start next slide before fadeOut finishes
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(slideShow, 1500); //start slideshow after 1500 msecs    
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2jwqhom/3/)

As a side note, if it would be ok to let the fadeout finish completely, you could simply do `$slider.fadeIn(2000).delay(1000).fadeOut(2000, slideShow);` instead of using setTimeout, but I reckoned your goal was to transition without fading out completely.